# is there a way to fetch only a deeply nested subdocument in mongoose by id?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

here is what my document looks like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9df11b0e0a6e032bf3117f"),
    "body" : ...
     ...
    "comments" : [            
        {
            "comment" : ..,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d9df46e0e0a6e032bf31182"),
            "replies" : [
                { 
                    "reply" : "reply to comment ",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9bec26301798056bb07ab5")
                },
                      ]
        }, 
    ],

}
```

i have to fetch only a reply by id and now im using

```
Album.findOne(query,"comments.replies.$").then(async (reply)=>{
const respo=await reply.comments[0].replies.find(data=>data._id==req.params.replyid)
```

....

is there a better way than this?? the above code fetches all the replies from comments subdocumnet

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`projection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) in this way:

```
db.collection.find({
  "comments.replies._id": ObjectId("5d9bec26301798056bb07ab5")
},
{
  "comments.replies.$": 1
})
```

This query look for a docuemnt where exists a value with the given `_id` into the `replies` array inside `comments` array.
And then uses projection to output only the value where positional operator is into `comments.replies.$`, i.e. the only value that match the `_id`.

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/M50u3zfNGHZ)

Comment: this still returns the whole reply array.
check https://mongoplayground.net/p/djXTXRro1iv
I  need to fetch the exact reply with id